# p:not(:hover) only active when another object is hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

in:

```
p:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Which would only highlight what is hovered, but I want to achieve an effect that would lower opacity of objects that aren't being hovered on. how do I do it?

the only "person" I could reach out to as someone new to programming was chatGPT that has failed me after many tries, or maybe it's me who can't spell my requirements correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use JavaScript. To make the effect `opacity: 0.6` for all items except the current item, you need to assign a hover to the parent item, and simultaneously assign the effect `opacity: 1` from the parent with the hover to the current item: `div:hover p:hover {}`

```css
p {
    background: green;
}

div:hover p {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

div:hover p:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work for my code...
`<div class="paragraf">
    <p class="slowo">bandyta</p>
</div>
<div class="paragraf">
    <p class="slowo">filantrop</p>
</div>`
idk what i did wrong but ur answer seems just right so its a problem on my side

Comment: @feelschrisman, https://jsfiddle.net/tpwhzg6a/1/

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating the code. What you want to do is much simpler than it seems. From what I understand you want to set `opacity: 1` only to the paragraph with the hover, and the rest set with `opacity: .6`

**CSS**

```
p {
    opacity: .6;
}

p:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

With this code, by default all paragraphs will have an opacity of 0.6, and when you hover over them, that particular paragraph will have an opacity of 1.

Comment: that's not what i meant fren